# How to set cakephp edit form custom url?

Tags: cakephp

HI,
  im accessing my edit_view using the url

```
/controller/action/group_id/id
```

but when i check my  action it is only using

```
/controller/action/id
```

i have already tried using the following.

```
$params = array('url' => array('controller' => 'controller','action'=> 'action',$group_id,$id))
$this->form(model,$params)

$params = array('url' => '/controller/action/group_id/id')
$this->form(model,$params)
```

but its still not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Don't really know what `$this->form()` is, but try:

```
echo $this->Form->create('SomeModel', array(
  'url' => array(
    'controller' => 'controller', 
    'action' => 'action', 
    $param_1, 
    $param_2
    )
  ));
```

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that there is no `$this->form` in CakePHP. What version are you using?